# Black screen with i915 driver on newly installed Gentoo system

Tags: drivers, gentoo, devuan, i915

I am trying to install Gentoo GNU/Linux on my laptop as a dual boot, the other OS being Devuan GNU/Linux (Chimaera).

Devuan is already installed and works properly. In particular, the video card works (text mode and X11 with mate desktop) without a problem.

In Gentoo, I have built the kernel without changing the default configuration. When booting Gentoo, after seeing the GRUB menu and the first kernel messages, the screen goes black and stays like that. The OS works though: I can ssh to the laptop and work on it remotely.

Here is the output of `lshw` on Gentoo (run inside an ssh session):

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 35
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:118 memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

and here is what the command says on Devuan:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 35
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:126 memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

So both use the same driver and report the same information about the controller.

This or similar problems seem to occur now and then, and I have found a few sources (see e.g. [this question](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235352)) that suggest to pass the following to the kernel:

```
i915.modeset=0
```

If I do this, I can get to the login console, but the image is flickering all the time and, from what I read in the arch forum, I won't be able to run X.
On the other hand, Devuan works without this option, so I guess it is not needed.

So is there some other option that I can use to make my graphics card work on Gentoo?

**Additional information**

Here is some more information about my Gentoo environment.

During the installation, I followed the [Gentoo AMD64 Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64) . I used `stage3-amd64-openrc-20221023T170534Z.tar.xz`.
I installed the kernel sources (see [Configuring the Linux kernel](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Kernel)) with

```
# emerge --ask sys-kernel/gentoo-sources
```

and got version `linux-5.15.75-gentoo`. I then started the kernel configuration tool with

```
# make menuconfig
```

Here, I did not change any options and just saved. This is what I meant above by saying that I have built the kernel without changing the default configuration.

I then built and installed with

```
# make && make modules_install
# make install
```

I built the ramfs with:

```
# emerge --ask sys-kernel/dracut
# dracut --kver=5.15.75-gentoo
```

**Another test**

Since my Gentoo installation is on an external USB disk, I tried booting on another laptop. This has the following graphics card:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:124 memory:af000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

This uses again the `i915` driver and the screen turns black during boot (I ran `lshw` inside an ssh session). As with the other laptop, with `i915.modeset=0` the problem goes away.

Comment: "In Gentoo, I have built the kernel without changing the default configuration". Which kernel ? gentoo-sources ? other ? which version ?

Comment: @MC68020: Good points. I have added more information at the end of my question.

Comment: Ha! For the first time running, I would have tested without any initramfs. BTW, as far as I can remember (more than 10 years ago) the initramfs was not a step required in the installation handbook. 10 years later… never realized the need for it anyway.

Comment: Maybe I do not need a ramfs in my installation. I will try removing the image.

Comment: Simply removing the ramfs image and re-creating the grub configuration make the system unbootable. Maybe the ramfs must be unregistered in some way (with dracut?) but I haven't found how to do this. I'll wait for other suggestions before I reinstall from scratch without a ramfs.

Comment: I just performed a new installation: default kernel configuration, no ramfs. Same problem: I need to pass `i915.modeset=0` to the kernel otherwise I have a black screen.

Comment: Read [this section](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Intel#Enable_early_KMS) of the Gentoo Intel Wiki